# Security update for Magento Open Source APSB22-12 Which version?

Tags: upgrade, security, patches

I need to run the new security patches on Magento Open Source 2.4.3 - 2.4.3-p1 but Adobe don't actually elaborate on how to choose the correct version. My guess would be the COMPOSER version, but I would like to understand this, so could someone please explain how you know which one to use?

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/4426353041293-Security-updates-available-for-Adobe-Commerce-APSB22-12-

https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/magento/apsb22-12.html

My open source instance was originally from an archive.

Comment: running threw the same interrogation as the patch can't be applied directly as it modify vendor files. Composer seems to be the good way but not sure the patch can be applied this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2 can be installed in two ways :

Github installation or Composer based Installation

A Github installation is usually used by developers who are contributing to the Magento codebase and is a clone of the Magento 2 github repo.

Production installations should use the composer based installation which downloads released packages of Magento 2 from the Magento composer repo.

A composer installation has the Magento core code located in /vendor/magento the github installation has the Magento core code located in /app/code

**Use the composer patch for your Magento 2 composer based installation.**

Attempting to use a github patch will fail as the patched files will not be found.

Comment: Thank you. That explains it perfectly. I had diffed the files and noticed the changes were in different locations, but wasn't sure why.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read this article.

```
https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028367731
```

Comment: I had read that article, but that just tells you how to patch it, and doesn't explain what the 2 versions are for. That's what I want to understand.